# AdventureWorksDW

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am just digging in the AWDW to understand it's structure and design logic. Here I'm specifically talking about FactProductInventory. As it's shown below, the first 21 rows are exactly the same except the recorded date is changed. [image: screenshot of SQL result]

Now when you continue down the table in ProductKet=1 you see that UnitCost is going up and down, without any change in UnitIn and UnitOut. What I understand is that no change in  Quantity is happening, but then why is the UnitCost changing? I hope this is a valid question.

Thanks

Comment: ... because `UnitCost` is changing. It need to be recorded somewhere. In an "OLTP" system (a system with a schema that is optimised for  writing into), you wouldn't see table like this. In an "OLAP" system, tables are optimised to make reading and analysis fast and easy.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. UnitCost normally changes when a new purchase happens, but because the UnitBalance is constantly at 875 that means no new purchase has happened, right?

Comment: As Nick said unitcost is changing- meaning consider the price of the Product having product_key as 1 has increased to .33 cents after 2005-07-21. Like everyday product whose price keeps on increasing day by day.

Comment: Ok, I got it, here Cost means Price, not the actual cost like Cost of Good Sold.

Comment: Perhaps unit cost changes when the Supplier changes it. We're guessing because this is fictional data so we don't know the real business process behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that table is modeled as a periodic snapshot fact table containing a snapshot of each product's stock, warehouse movement (in/out) and cost, at the end of each day. Therefore, the grain of analysis permitted by the table is the time period rather than the actual transactions (i.e. the actual movement or changes in products).

Periodic snapshot fact tables are useful for cases like this, when the business need is focused on understanding a quantity of items in a given stated, over a time period (e.g. "how many units of product X in stock between 2016 and 2017" in this case, or "how many items were in each stage of our manufacturing line"):

You can read more about periodic snapshot fact tables and how they relate to other fact modelling techniques [here](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/06/design-tip-167-complementary-fact-table-types/), I'll leave you a relevant edited quotation:

> Supporting analysis of inventory levels is a task well suited for a periodic snapshot fact table. (...) The periodic snapshot fact table does an excellent job of helping
>   understand the volume of *items* in our pipeline. It answers the “how
>   much?” question. How much total inventory do we have?